# Why I can't change from "High Contrast" theme on Eclipse Luna 4.4.2?

Tags: eclipse, themes

One of the the things that made me switch from Kepler to Luna was the promise that I could have a full eclipse dark theme. So I've installed the [MoonRise UI Theme](https://github.com/guari/eclipse-ui-theme), but when I go to Window -> General -> Appearance to finally change the theme, I get this wonderful gray area locked on "High Contrast":

[image]

I've also installed the "themes" plugin from the Eclipse Marketplace, and everything seems fine, **except** for the fact that it isn't, and I've googled it and everyone seems to be happy with one's own dark theme, but I'm out of it.

So, why?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I've found the reason why (And it's a rather obscure one). I'm using Windows 7, and I've disabled the "Themes" service from Windows in order to save some memory.

As I was going to take more coffee, I remembered that Eclipse was implemented in Java, and that although it is cross-platform, the theme part from Eclipse must use something from AWT and use the "Themes" service from Windows (And then I've noticed that "High Contrast" was exactly the same one I was using (And the only one available), after I've disabled the service). So, I've pressed WINDOWS BUTTON + R, typed "services.msc", enabled the "Themes" service again, switched the windows theme to the memory-consuming one, and, voilà, now I was able to switch the theme in Eclipse to MoonRise.

So, if someone uses Windows and gets this problem, that's how to solve it.